# Initializing few specific values in an array, set rest to default

Tags: c#, arrays, initialization

Is there a way to declare an array with 60 values like this (few specific values, the rest will be calculated later on):

```
long[] l = { 1, 2, new long[58] };
```

instead of having to waste 2 lines for something like this:

```
long[] l = new long[60];
l[0] = 1;
l[1] = 2;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize the full array (which would give all elements default value), and then use `Array.Copy` to only populate part of it from a fixed, shorter array:

```
int[] arr = new int[60];
Array.Copy(new[] {1, 2, 3}, arr, 3);
```

A more extravagant (and wasteful) method would be to use LINQ:

```
int[] arr = new[] {1, 2, 3}.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(0, 57)).ToArray();
```

There's another funny way based on the `Array` API, and that is to resize the small array to fit the large size. This process will assign all new elements the default value:

```
int[] arr = new[] {1, 2, 3};
Array.Resize(ref arr, 60);
```

Comment: Why is it more wasteful? Can you explain?

Comment: Because `ToArray()` will use the `GetEnumerator()` + `MoveNext()` 60 times, let alone that it will have to walk through the sequence twice to convert it to an array because it would first have to know the length of the sequence, and the sequence constructed with `Concat()` cannot tell that efficiently. `Array.Copy`, at the same time, would know everything up-front and, with some luck, it would yield a single CPU instruction when compiled.

Comment: I just measured it, and the first variant is 4x faster on a 60-items array. On a 1000-items array, the first variant is 17x faster.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on a single line initialization, you can use C# collection initializer syntax to construct a `List<long>`, and then convert that list to an array:

```
long[] data = new List<long>(new long[60]) {[0]=1, [1]=2}.ToArray();
```

Unfortunately, the new C# indexer initialization does not apply to arrays, so this approach remains inefficient. However, this inefficiency would not be detectable when you are talking about arrays of size 60 or even 600 elements, because creation and disposal of the throw-away 60-element array would be "in the noise" of time measurement.